# How to add auto-completion to Notepad++ for Objective-C?

Tags: notepad++

Auto-completion XML files exist for Notepad++ in the notepad++\plugins\apis folder. However I can't find Objective-C there.

Does anyone have an XML file for Objective-C auto-completion, or perhaps another solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by [this official list from NpWiki++](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Language_Files#O) none has defined an user language definition file and an autocompletion file for Objective-C. If I were you, I would select a text editor, that supports auto completion for Objective-C, otherwise you should keep an eye on that list and wait, if somebody will post an XML for Objective-C.